# Adding email address to Linktree

Tags: links, profile

I'm trying to set up a Linktree page... I've added some links to my social media profiles but would also like to have an 'email' link which would work in the same way as a `mailto` link in HTML.

I can't find a way to do this, and can't find anything on Google or YouTube. I would have thought it would be a standard feature.

Is it possible to do this in Linktree?

Comment: Asking for web app recommendations is off-topic on this site but they are on topic in [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible as links URL should start with `https://`

It's possible to add a link using a "social media" icon on the footer but not for free as this feature require to suscribe to the PRO version.

From [Using the Social Links feature](https://help.linktr.ee/en/support/solutions/articles/48001153438-using-the-social-links-feature) (follow this link to see the clickable links)

> Linktree is a great place to link your audience to the different social platforms you have a presence on. The PRO subscription allows you to link various social media profiles as icons at the bottom of your Linktree. The Social Links section is found by clicking on the Settings tab in your Admin page

...

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | How to add your Email | To add your email as a social icon, type in your email address. For example: thisisatestemail@gmail.com Please note: this is an example email address, you will need to use your own. |

Answer (score 4):

It's not actually possible to do that, but there is a work around for that.

You can use https://mailxto.com to generate a prefilled email with a shortened URL that can be shared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2022, you can add a "Contact Details" widget that automatically generates a "mailto" link once you provide your email address. Just go to `Explore > Contact Details` and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings --> Social Icons and search for the word 'email.' You can add it as an icon at the top or bottom of your LinkTree. Does not require a PRO account.

Answer (score -1):

One potential solution could be to use an external website to redirect users to a `mailto` link. This would allow you to provide the email as part of the urland the site could use javascript to redirect anyone clicking that link to the mailto address.

There is an example of such a website at https://moralcode.github.io/MailtoRedirect, although you should only use it (as with any website) if you trust its author since its technically possible for them to see any email addresses that are being used with the site. You can also inspect the website code to ensure that the site is not doing anything malicious.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated the answer to include a link to an example of a website that can perform such redirection